# Переместить элементы на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть пример разметки, но вложенность примерно такая:

```
<div class = "tistimonials">
    <div class = "testimonail-common">
        <div class = "testimonial-content">
            <div class = "testimonial-content__special"></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "testimonial-content2">
            <div class = "tistimonial-wrapper">
                <div class = "testimonial-example">пример</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "testimonail-common">
        <div class = "testimonial-content">
            <div class = "testimonial-content__special"></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "testimonial-content2">
            <div class = "tistimonial-wrapper">
                <div class = "testimonial-example">пример2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно блок с классом `.testimonial-example` переместить в блок с классом `.testimonial-content__special` при том чтобы родительский блок `.testimonail-common` был один и тот же, то есть не нужно скидывать все `.testimonial-example` в первый блок `.testimonial-content__special`, а чтобы перемещения были все внутри `.testimonail-common`.

Вот такой код скидывает все блоки `.testimonial-example` на странице в первый `.testimonial-content__special`:

```
$('.testimonial-example').appendTo($(".testimonial-content__special"));
```

Вот пытался написать что-то такое, но не работает:

```
$('.testimonial-example').appendTo(.closest($(".testimonial-content__special")));
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильно используешь `closest()`.
Лучше сделать так:

```
$(".testimonial-example").each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.testimonail-common').find(".testimonial-content__special").append(this);
});
```

Comment: да, спасибо, я уже сделал примерно так же)